# Python Plotting Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
list = [1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8,10]
plot(list)
```

With my code above, the code will graph with x-axis run from 0 to 8. What should I do if I want my x-axis run from another value? i.e. my x-axis run from 120-128?

Comment: This seems rather basic, is it not covered in the documentation?

Comment: And you should not name your lists as `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `show()` function to show the graph.
Your code should look something like this.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
list = [1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8,10]
plot(list)
show()
```

And also, as mentioned in the comments by @BcK, don't use keywords or in-built function names as variable names, finally don't `import *` , this is not a good practice. You can update your whole program to this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
var_list =  [1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8,10] # don't use keywords or inbuilt function names as varible names 
plt.plot(var_list)
plt.show()  # this is to visualize the plot
```